# Angular-translate (Pascalprecht) $translate service is not returning a promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I´m using angular-translate (Pascalprecht) plugin to translate my Angular1.0.7 web application.

In some point I need to use the $translate service inside my controller (sometimes you need it). The call `$scope.departurePhoto = $translate(photoName);` is not translated anymore, because at the time it is run, the translations service `$translate.uses(language).then(function() {` is still running.

I have read in the official doc https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service , it´s supposed the $translate service returns a promise to do something like:

```
$translate(photoName).then(function (departurePhoto) {
                    $scope.departurePhoto = departurePhoto;
                    console.log("destinationHelper.departurePhoto=" + $scope.departurePhoto);
                }, function (translationId) {
                    $scope.departurePhoto = translationId;
                    console.log("destinationHelper.departurePhoto con translationId=" + $scope.departurePhoto);
                });
```

Howerver, I´m getting error in the call: `TypeError: $translate(...).then is not a function`

Is it working since the beginning or from any specific version? I´m using pretty old angular-translate 1.1.0 min. version.

Note: I have tried to upgrade to the latest stable angular-translate version. It´s supposed all versions are compatible, so just replaced the lib files and it didn´t worked. I got next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: g.has is not a function     at Constructor.$get (angular-translate.min.js:6)
```

I know these are two problems, so I would like to fix my problem without upgrading first if possible.

Comment: $translate service wasnt available from the start. Here is the change log https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
Also if you bump to latest version of angular-translate you can use $translate.instant() rather than a async call

Comment: The $translate service is available in my version. I use successfully in other points. What it seems it´s not working is the fact that the service returns a promise, so I cannot use .then. As said at the end of the post, to upgrade to the latest version is not working. So, any workaraound?

Comment: $translate('photoName') perhaps.... and how about $translate.instant()
 $scope.departurePhoto = $translate.instant('photoName');

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions, but did you read carefully the problem and the comments?

Comment: Maybe i didnt understand your requirement/comments.... but $translate service is expected to return promise and .then will resolve the promise...And as per my understanding you asked for work around and $translate.instant() is infact the preferred way...